# Is $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ ,if } x=\frac{1}{n} \\ 0 \quad \, \, \, \,\text{ ,if } x=0\end{cases}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let Is $D:=\{1/n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}, f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} &\text{if } x=\frac{1}{n}, \\ 0 &\text{if } x=0.\end{cases}\quad$ Where is $f$ continuous?

**My attempt:**

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta >0$, then $\forall x,x_0\in D\backslash \{0\}$:

$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies \left| \frac{(-1)^x}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{(-1)^{x_0}}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right |<\varepsilon$$\left| \frac{(-1)^x}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{(-1)^{x_0}}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right |=\left |\frac{(-1)^x\cdot \sqrt{x_0}-(-1)^{x_0}\cdot \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x_0}}\right |\leq \left |\frac{(-1)^x\cdot \sqrt{x_0}-(-1)^{x_0}\cdot \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right  |=\left |(-1)^x-\frac{(-1)^{x_0}}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right |$ This does not seem to work out, what would be a good way show where $f$ is continious?

Comment: And what are the values of $f(x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $x \notin \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$? Do you only define $f$ on $D$?

Comment: yes, $f$ is solely defined on $D$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic If you see it as a topological space, you must clear which topology and metric you use. Also in this case you must clear which space is your range exactly? If your function is onto, and use discrete metric, so the answer is obviously YES.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity at $0$ follows from $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt x$ for all $x$. [Take $\delta =\epsilon^{2}$]. Continuity at any other point $x$ follows from the fact that $y=x$ whenever $|y-x|$ is sufficiently small.

To be explicit $x=\frac 1 n$ and $|y-x| <\frac 1 {n(n+1)}$ implies $y=x$. So choose $\delta = \frac 1 {n(n+1)}$ whatever your $\epsilon$ is.